# Roslyn Object Initialization new keyword

Tags: c#, syntax, format, new-operator, roslyn

I'm trying to write a method that will instantiate a object given is property

I've come up with something along theese lines :

```
public static LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax GetVariableWithDeclarationWithInitialization(string pVariableType, string pVariableName, InitializerExpressionSyntax pInitializer)
{
       return SyntaxFactory.LocalDeclarationStatement(SyntaxFactory.VariableDeclaration(SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName(pVariableType)).WithTrailingTrivia(SyntaxFactory.Space)
                                                                   .WithVariables(SyntaxFactory.SingletonSeparatedList(SyntaxFactory.VariableDeclarator(SyntaxFactory.Identifier(pVariableName))
                                                                                                                                    .WithInitializer(SyntaxFactory.EqualsValueClause(SyntaxFactory.ObjectCreationExpression(SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName(pVariableType)
                                                                                                                                                                                                  .WithInitializer(pInitializer)))
                                                                                                                                    )));
}
```

But this generate the following code :

```
            ObjectTest test = newObjectTest 
            {
                prop1 = random.Next(0, 2) == 0 , 
                prop2 = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() , 
                prop3 = random.Next(0, 100)}

            ;
```

There's a few problem with that ...
But manly the fact that the new keyword is missing a space after, even though i've added a trivia ?
I'd like it to generate something like this :

```
           ObjectTest test = new ObjectTest 
           {
                prop1 = random.Next(0, 2) == 0, 
                prop2 = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), 
                prop3 = random.Next(0, 100)
           };
```

I don't know what im missing... i've put the code it should generate in the 
[Roslyn Quoter](https://github.com/KirillOsenkov/RoslynQuoter)
And it gave me something like the first link!
Also I've tried using the NormalizeWhiteSpace() method on the LocalDeclarationStatement but it formats the object Initalization like this :

```
           ObjectTest test = new ObjectTest{
               prop1 = random.Next(0, 2) == 0, prop2 = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), prop3 = random.Next(0, 100)};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `WithLeadingTrivia` instead of `WithTrailingTrivia` (of course if there is such method).

I guess you just adding a space after the Type name (but not after the `new` keyword)